# Disable an asp.net button postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, postback, webforms

I tried to disable an asp.net button but failed.
The error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1501: No overload for method 'btnUnlock_Click' takes '0' arguments
```

Source Error:

```
 Line 99:         <asp:Button ID="btnUnlock" runat="server" Text="Unlock User" Visible="False"       OnClick ="btnUnlock_Click()" />
```

And

```
 protected void btnUnlock_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(userName);
        user.UnlockUser();
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: try <asp:Button ID="btnUnlock" runat="server" Text="Unlock User" Visible="False"       OnClick ="btnUnlock_Click" />

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `OnClientClick="return false;"` to disabled postback. You can try this

```
<asp:button runat="server".... OnClientClick="return false;" />
```

In C# you can disable button by

```
btnUnlock.IsEnabled = false;
```

[IsEnabled Property MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.isenabled.aspx)

Comment: The question is where is the good place to put "btnUnlock.IsEnabled = false;". In click event/Page_LOad or other place? The example has another button to disable it. What I want is to disable it automatelly after clicking it.

Comment: As you said `I want is to disable it automatelly after clicking it.` then it should be in `Click` event. If you want to disable it on button click then put it in click event.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems here:

```
OnClick="btnUnlock_Click()"
```

This syntax is incorrect.  To set up your server-side click handler, write it like this:

```
OnClick="btnUnlock_Click"
```

Also, your question title doesn't seem to relate to this code at all.  If you're wanting to know how to disable the server-side click handling client-side, you can add a *client-side* click handler, like this:

```
OnClientClick="return false;"
```

...or some custom client-side function.  To disable it server-side, simply don't add the `OnClick` attribute.